# Disabling a control with Pixate Freestyle

Tags: ios, xamarin, pixate

I have a UIButton with the following css

```
button {
    size: 50 100;
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

But I want to disable the button based on a style like maybe:

```
button {
    size: 50 100;
    color: #FF0000;
    enabled: true;
}
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish or add an extension method to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are `enabled` or `disabled` pseudo-classes available for `UIButton`. What you could potentially do instead is detect the button state and assign a `styleClass` dynamically like this:

```
#import <PixateFreestyle/PixateFreestyle.h>

UIButton *button = [UIButton new];

if(button.enabled){
  button.styleClass = @"myButton";
}else{
  button.styleClass = @"myButtonDisabled";
}
```

...and then your CSS would be:

```
.myButton {
    /* Default button styles */
}
.myButtonDisabled {
    /* Disabled button styles */
}
```

I hope that helps. Good luck.